# windowsPhone 8: Add json data to listview.Template inside stackpanel without using modal

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I want to add json data to the stackpanel (Name:expand) inside listview items by using C# code without using modal...
I have parsed json data...but i dont know how to attach it to listview Items inside my stackpanel named "Expand" without using modal
This is my XAML

```
    <ListView.Items>
                </ListView.Items>                

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>

                      <Border Tapped="Border_Tap" Height="90">
                         <StackPanel  x:Name="ParentStackPanel" Width="380" Margin="0,5,0,5">



                                <StackPanel Background="Black" Margin="60,-80,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CompanyName1}" FontSize="20" FontStyle="Normal">

                                    </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel> 

<StackPanel DataContext="expand1"  Name="expand" Background="White" Height="220">



                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

My Json is Given Below

I want to attach each of Invoice json object to listview Item stackpanel (Name = "expand") without using modal

```
  {
  "Example": [
    {
      "Invoice": {
        "TF": " 200",
        "BF": " 200",
        "MD": "10",
        "EFM": " 12",
        "ATT": "4"
      },
      "TF": "200"
    },
    {
      "Invoice": {
        "TF": " 49",
        "BF": " 49",
        "MD": "4",
        "EFM": " 14",
        "ATT": "4"
      },
      "TF": "49"
    },
    {
      "Invoice": {
        "TF": " 49",
        "BF": " 49",
        "MD": "3",
        "FPK": " 16",
        "ATT": "4"
      },
      "TF": "49"
    },
    {
      "Invoice": {
        "TF": " 49",
        "BF": " 49",
        "MD": "2",
        "FPK": " 12",
        "ATT": "1"
      },
      "TF": "49"
    },
    {
      "Invoice": {
        "TF": " 90",
        "BF": " 90",
        "MD": "4",
        "FPK": " 12",
        "ATT": "4"
      },
      "TF": "90"
    },
    {
      "Invoice": {
        "TF": " 49",
        "BF": " 49",
        "MD": "3",
        "FPK": " 16",
        "ATT": "4"
      },
      "TF": "49"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: try to do dynamic deserialization, or deserialization to object

Answer (score 0):

thanks to http://json2csharp.com/ getting classes for your json is very handy:

```
public class Invoice
{
     public string TF { get; set; }
     public string BF { get; set; }
     public string MD { get; set; }
     public string EFM { get; set; }
     public string ATT { get; set; }
     public string FPK { get; set; }
 }

 public class Example
 {
     public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
     public string TF { get; set; }
 }

 public class RootObject
 {
     public List<Example> Example { get; set; }
 }
```

then download Json.NET http://www.newtonsoft.com/json from NuGet and deserialize your json:

```
var objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

finally set your `listView.ItemSource` property equal to `objects` and be sure to use the same property name indicated in the classes above.
If you want to use different names, try something like this:

Example:

```
public class Invoice
{
     [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "CompanyName1")]
     public string TF { get; set; }

     [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ComapnyName2")]
     public string BF { get; set; }
 }
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: You have used modal...i want without using modal